# JavaScript error detected in a third-party plugin - TypeError: a.browser is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, scripting

i am trying to implement a carousel slide of youtube embed videos into a wordpress page. The same as in this thread: [Slider/Carousel in Bootstrap with Youtube video and a description on the other side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266809/slider-carousel-in-bootstrap-with-youtube-video-and-a-description-on-the-other-s)
but with no description

I have hueman live composer and i am trying to add it in html because i cannot use plugins currently. 
The video slider works fine, except it reduces the size of the entire webpage and i get this error as title.

Is there some code workaround? Thanks

I tried to add the migrate script but did not work. I mean this
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js">
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js">

I cannot install plugins and cannot update anything right now.

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1 data-rsssl=1>

<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-box">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The question as written is a bit too vague to get much useful feedback from the community.  You might want to review [ask] and get a feel for a different way to describe your problem.  Remember, Stack Overflow is intended for _specific programming questions_ -- properly formed questions are the ones best answers by the community.  Good luck!

Comment: Hello alexander, thanks for your reply. I tried to be more specific, but i don0t really know if i made it better. I am not a coder so i don't really understand fully the issue myself.